# Spideroak website login

Tags: cloud, storage

I've just started using SpiderOak and followed the suggested TNO (Trust No One) or Zero-Knowledge privacy approach of installing the application first.

Now I want to login to the web site but need to use my login credentials:

https://spideroak.com/browse/login/storage

It says if I want "Zero-Knowledge" privacy, then I should only use the locally installed app.

I was only going to log in to "see" what was there.  Does SpiderOak allow you to have a separate login for your web account and only use your "private login/password" if you want to access your data through the web?

I haven't been able to find this answer on their web site (but it might be there).

Answer (score 1):

The user preferences or billing link can take you there. It's hidden as a right-click context menu in the running systray icon of the SpiderOak app. You can see account details. If you navigate to see your data, you will have to enter your credentials, AFAIU violating TNO.
By the way, another context-link will create an active session for the user forums, where you will be authenticated. If you haven't done or considered it, you can post your question there. However, I'm rather sure I answered it correctly, of course.